# Android: WebView with custom font (Arial) used by External Website & CSS

Tags: android, css, fonts, android-webview

Is it possible to include a TTF font (Arial) in my Android application that can be used by an externally loaded webpage's CSS?

For Example, let's say my site it http://www.some-site.com and it has a CSS file with the following:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: "CustomArial"; 
    src: url('Arial.ttf'); 
}

h1 {  
    font-family: 'CustomArial', serif;
}
```

I've also tried setting the url src of the font-face to the following, which none of them worked:

- `/mnt/sdcard/Arial.ttf`
- `file://mnt/sdcard/Arial.ttf`

I know this works if the Arial.ttf file lives in the same directory as the CSS file on the server, but what I want to do is be able to use the Arial.ttf that is in my app's /assets folder, or somewhere that I've placed it on the SDCard.  Reasoning is because the Arial.ttf file is 775kb and this will need to be downloaded by the user before the page is rendered.

Is this even possible?  I know that I can accomplish this if the HTML that I'm loading into the WebView lives locally and I would load it via WebView.loadData(), but I need to use WebView.loadUrl().

Any thoughts/help would be great!

Comment: Just so you know, its not legal to embed Arial in your apk or host it on your web server for redistribution unless you have a license.  Font licensing is one of the reasons Android only includes their Roboto and Droid fonts.  There are many open source fonts out there that are close to Arial.  Check out the Bitstream Vera fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I am aware of this.

Comment: Hey @hooked82 quite a long time have passed since this post but have u solved this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

1) put the font in the assets folder of your project, not on the SD card.  create a folder in your project named `assets`

2) reference it in your `@font-face` with 
   `src: url('file:///android_asset/Arial.ttf');`

Comment: This doesn't work.  I've tried every iteration with every possible file path and it doesn't work.  I was able to get it working if I placed the Font in the assets folder and referenced it from an HTML file that lived in the assets folder as well, but I need to use a local TTF Font on an Externally loaded webpage by referencing it somehow.

Comment: What if you put a CSS file in the assets folder that defines the font and add that CSS file to the WebView? Paths in `url()` are relative to the CSS file and not the HTML file.

Comment: How would I add the CSS file to the WebView?  Via loadData()?

Comment: @hooked82 I don't know shit about Android dev, but i think it is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/style.css" />`. Then, in your css, reference the font relative to the stylesheet's dir.